# Passing a string variable from one file to another. STM32CubeIDE

Tags: c, stm32, stm32cubeide

this code is receiving either '1' or '0' through usb serial com port. If it is '1' then the LED turns on. If it is '0' the LED turns off. The following code works just fine if i use it in the file "usbd_cdc_if.c"....

```
static int8_t CDC_Receive_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint32_t *Len)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  USBD_CDC_SetRxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, &Buf[0]);
  USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);
  if(Buf[0] == '1'){
     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  }
  else if(Buf[0] == '0'){
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_13, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  }
  return (USBD_OK);
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
```

But instead, i wanted to have the if statement in the "main.c" file rather than the "usbd_cdc_if.c" file. So both would look like this:

"usbd_cdc_if.c" file:

```
extern char serialCopy[];


static int8_t CDC_Receive_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint32_t *Len)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  USBD_CDC_SetRxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, &Buf[0]);
  USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);
  memcpy(serialCopy,Buf,*Len);
  return (USBD_OK);
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
```

"main.c" file:

```
char serialCopy[MAX_LEN];

while (1)
{
    if(strcmp(serialCopy, "1") == 0){
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOK, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    }
    else if(strcmp(serialCopy, "0") == 0){
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOK, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    }
}
```

When trying to copy the variable value from "usbd_cdc_if.c" to "main.c". The LED wouldnt work when i use my method. Why? Thanks

Comment: You expect the data in `serialCopy` to be a null-terminated string. But the `CDC_Receive_FS` function doesn't null-terminate the buffer as a string.

Comment: ok...I tried adding Buf[*Len] = '\0'; at the end of the CDC_Receive_FS function after memcpy, but it doesnt work. Did i do it right?

Comment: How, when and where is `CDC_Receive_FS` called? When does it set the contents of `serialCopy`, and when is your code checking it? Is `serialCopy` a proper global variable? When and where is it really defined? Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: Also please don't "fix" the code in the question. That makes the question useless as it no longer have the problem being asked about. If something from a comment solves the problem, as the person to write an answer instead. That way you can accept it, vote on it, and other people can read the question and the answers if they have the same (or a similar) problem.

Comment: What @Someprogrammerdude says. I was writing an answer about this just as the question suddenly changed. I therefore did a rollback of edits.

Comment: `serialCopy` should be `volatile`

Comment: @Flexz Why? How can you tell that any of this is called from inside an ISR?

Comment: My fault about edit.
Now i cant understand why its not working. All i did was pass the variable from one file to another and use the if statement in the second file instead.

Comment: **note: The GPIOK, GPIO_PIN_3 pin numbers in my first and last block of code are actually the same i never eddited it here.

Answer (score 1):

You changed the code. `Buf[0] == '1'` does not mean the same as `strcmp(serialCopy, "1") == 0` since the latter assumes a null terminated string. Characters sent over serial buses are not null terminated unless you explicitly sent them as such.

Additionally, strings entered from a terminal on a PC are followed by a line feed character `\n` (*nix-like systems) or `\r\n` (Windows). Meaning that `strcmp("1", "1\n");` will fail even if the string is correctly null terminated.

You should view the received data in the rx buffer using a debugger to see what you actually got.

Comment: As for the serial string issue.....the first block of code is working fine. I am receiving 1 or 0 and the LED is turning of and off. I just dont know how to pass the string variable. Isnt there a way to copy and paste the same format of the string variable from one file to the other?

Comment: @SomeStudent "Isnt there a way to copy and paste the same format of the string variable from one file to the other?" That's what you are doing and apparently where your problems come from. Like I say, view what data you actually picked up by your debugger.

Answer (score -1):

Solved. The problem was that memcpy() in the usbd_cdc_if.c file is ony copying the data once but the loop in the main.c file keeps checking. Needed to use a global variable....

usbd_cdc_if.c file:

```
uint8_t newVariable = 0;

static int8_t CDC_Receive_FS(uint8_t* Buf, uint32_t *Len)
{
  USBD_CDC_SetRxBuffer(&hUsbDeviceFS, &Buf[0]);
  USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);
  newVariable = Buf[0];
  return (USBD_OK);
}
```

main.c file:

```
extern uint8_t newVariable;

while (1)
{
    if(newVariable == '1'){
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOK, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    }
    else if(newVariable == '0'){
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOK, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    }
}
```

Now, it is working. I am not sure why all my tries didnt work.
Thank you.

Comment: Wasn't the old `serialCopy` a global variable?

Comment: Yes, but for some reason it didnt work. Now it does with the new code. I dont understand lol.

Comment: This actualy looks like you've stubled upon a workaround, while making random changes, no? This is a bad practice. I'd walk through all the questions and advices, asked in the comments, to find the actual root of the problem. Perhaps in the next task you'll have to copy the whole array.